# How to create a new Git experiment on DAGsHub

Tags: git, dagshub

To create a new experiment on **DAGsHub** using Git, what should be the format of `".._metrics.csv"` and `".._params.yml"` files?

Unfortunately, I can't find a reference anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:
For the metrics.csv file:

```
Name,Value,Timestamp,Step
loss,2.29,1573118607163,1
epoch,0,1573118607163,1
loss,2.26,1573118607366,11
epoch,0,1573118607366,11
loss,1.44,1573118607572,21
epoch,0,1573118607572,21
loss,0.65,1573118607773,31
avg_val_loss,0.17,1573118812491,3375
```

For the params.yml

```
batch_size: 32
learning_rate: 0.02
max_nb_epochs: 2
```

You can find more in-depth explanations here:

https://dagshub.com/docs/reference/git-tracking/#metrics-schema

https://dagshub.com/docs/reference/git-tracking/#parameter-schema